# Is there any method to retry within maxAttempts times using Acknowledge.nack for spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to use [consuming batches](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RC1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html) in kafka, and I found the document said retry is not supported as follows.

> Retry within the binder is not supported when using batch mode, so maxAttempts will be overridden to 1. You can configure a SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler (using a ListenerContainerCustomizer) to achieve similar functionality to retry in the binder. You can also use a manual AckMode and call Ackowledgment.nack(index, sleep) to commit the offsets for a partial batch and have the remaining records redelivered. Refer to the Spring for Apache Kafka documentation for more information about these techniques

If I use Acknowledge.nack(index,sleep), it will retry infinitely when error happens. Is there any method to retry within maxAttempts times using Acknowledge.nack?

The code is as like

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void consume(@Payload List<PayLoad> payloads, @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        
        try {
            consume(payloads);
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            acknowledgment.nack(0, 50);
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not; you have to keep track of the retry count yourself.

However, since version 2.5, you can now use a `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` where you throw a specific exception to tell the handler which record failed and it commits the offsets for the records before that one and applies retry logic to the failed record.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh